# How to locate an element which have same name and same atrributes in selenium and insert some text

Tags: java, selenium

When we get more than one element which are same in attribute and name like multiple textbox with same name and same class.There are no way to distingues those element.I want to insert different value for each textbox as located. How do we resolve this? Kindly advise , Thanks you

My WEB IMAGE : 
[image]

MY HTML CODE :

```
<tr class="model-added">


<td class="table_bg1 textTr">上2级代理佣金</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="upRebate[]" value="" maxlength="18">
               <td class="table_bg1 textTr">上3级代理佣金</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="upRebate[]" value="" maxlength="18">
```

MY CODE :

```
WebDriverWait insert3 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
                        insert3.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@name='upRebate[]'])[position()=2]")))
                                .sendKeys(dealerAmount);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution i have figure it out :

```
List<WebElement> li = driver.findElements(By.name(Constant.YHTY_Commission_upRebate));
            li.get(1).sendKeys(dealerAmountList2);
            System.out.println("INSERT 上2级代理佣金 :  " + dealerAmountList2);
            Log.info("INSERT 上2级代理佣金 :  " + dealerAmountList2);
            li.get(2).sendKeys(dealerAmountList3);
            System.out.println("INSERT 上2级代理佣金 :   " + dealerAmountList3);
            Log.info("INSERT 上2级代理佣金 :  " + dealerAmountList3);
            li.get(3).sendKeys(dealerAmountList4);
            System.out.println("INSERT 上2级代理佣金 :  " + dealerAmountList4);
            Log.info("INSERT 上2级代理佣金 :  " + dealerAmountList4);
```

Comment: Adding to this answer, there's a method specifically called findElementsByName.